# Simultaneous fields

Tags: typescript

I want to express in typescript that class has 2 fields and either they both are presented or they both are missing. So I want a check of any of these fields to be enough to consider them both defined.

[Example:](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20I%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20x%3A%20number%0D%0A%20%20%20%20y%3A%20number%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20x%3F%3A%20number%20%26%20(this%20is%20I)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20y%3F%3A%20number%20%26%20(this%20is%20I)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20f(obj%3A%20I)%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20var%20c%3A%20C%0D%0A%0D%0Ac.x%20%26%26%20f(c)%20%2F%2F%20should%20be%20ok%0D%0Ac.y%20%26%26%20f(c)%20%2F%2F%20should%20be%20ok%0D%0Af(c)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20should%20be%20error)

```
interface I {
    x: number
    y: number
}

class C {
    x?: number & (this is I)
    y?: number & (this is I)
}

declare function f(obj: I)

declare var c: C

c.x && f(c) // should be ok
c.y && f(c) // should be ok
f(c)        // should be error
```

But it doesn't work because of

> A type predicate is only allowed in return type position for functions and methods.

Any solutions?

Comment: Is this a run time check? Do you want to verify at run time if both are not `undefined`?

Comment: @AviadP., no, I want compile-time check. And in runtime I want to verify only one field. Actually I have 9 fields that are either all blank, or all dom elements.

Comment: If this is a compile time check, then you need nothing else. Your existing function signature will ensure that all arguments ever passed to it will have well defined `x` and `y` fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `C` type is more of a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) than an `interface` or `class`:

```
interface I {
  x: number
  y: number
}

type C = I | { x?: undefined, y?: undefined }

declare function f(obj: I): void;
declare var c: C

c.x && f(c) // ok
c.y && f(c) // ok
f(c)        // error
```

If you really need a `class` for the `C` type you can make a properly-named constructor but will need to [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) that it is of the right type, because the compiler can't verify it:

```
class _C {
  x?: number;
  y?: number;

  constructor(); // take no args
  constructor(x: number, y: number); // or take both x and y args
  constructor(x?: number, y?: number) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}
// assert that the _C class makes C instances
const C = _C as { new(): C, new(x: number, y: number): C }
```

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

---

Update: I see that you're having problems with this code for some reason, but I don't know why.  Check out the [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%2F%2F%20%20note%3A%20turn%20on%20--strictNullChecks%20in%20the%20Options%0A%0Ainterface%20I%20%7B%0A%20%20x%3A%20number%0A%20%20y%3A%20number%0A%7D%0A%0Atype%20C%20%3D%20I%20%7C%20%7B%20x%3F%3A%20undefined%2C%20y%3F%3A%20undefined%20%7D%0A%0Adeclare%20function%20f%28obj%3A%20I%29%3A%20void%3B%0Adeclare%20var%20c%3A%20C%0A%0Ac.x%20%26%26%20f%28c%29%20%2F%2F%20ok%0Ac.y%20%26%26%20f%28c%29%20%2F%2F%20ok%0Af%28c%29%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20error%0A%0Adeclare%20function%20f%28obj%3A%20I%29%3A%20void%3B%0A%0Aclass%20_C%20%7B%0A%20%20x%3F%3A%20number%3B%0A%20%20y%3F%3A%20number%3B%0A%0A%20%20constructor%28%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20take%20no%20args%0A%20%20constructor%28x%3A%20number%2C%20y%3A%20number%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20or%20take%20both%20x%20and%20y%20args%0A%20%20constructor%28x%3F%3A%20number%2C%20y%3F%3A%20number%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.x%20%3D%20x%3B%0A%20%20%20%20this.y%20%3D%20y%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%2F%2F%20assert%20that%20the%20_C%20class%20makes%20C%20instances%0Aconst%20C%20%3D%20_C%20as%20%7B%20new%28%29%3A%20C%2C%20new%28x%3A%20number%2C%20y%3A%20number%29%3A%20C%20%7D) and remember to turn on `--strictNullChecks` in the Options.  (After all, you are trying to check against `undefined` values for `x` or `y` as a type guard to determine if `C` is an `I` or not... so it's important for the compiler to correctly pay attention to `null` and `undefined` values).

Comment: I need class. Don't understand how to use your example with class (it contains compilation error also). Can you give a full example please? By the way, you version with type does NOT work too.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, sorry.  As far as I can tell, the above code is a full and working example.    I've edited the answer to include a Playground link to show it working.  Do you have `--strictNullChecks` on?  If not you should enable it.  If so and you still get errors could you explain where they are?

Comment: For the first code flag really helps. But for the second I see _"Cannot find name 'C'.":_ https://i.stack.imgur.com/jARbb.png

Comment: You removed the `type C =` line?  That would be the problem. The type and the value are both needed.

Comment: Ok, understood now. I thought it is an alternative solution, but it was an addition.

Comment: But wait. Seems like I can't use it inside of the class: `this.x && f(this);` is broken.

Comment: Ok, solved it: `doSmth(this: C) { this.x && f(this); c.x && f(c); }`.